# What is the difference between brushes and "MyPaint brushes" windows?

Tags: gimp

Why are there two brushes windows, one called "My paint brushes" and the other "brushes".

I'm wondering, how one effect the other when I'm using the brush tool?[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyPaint brushes are an implementation of brushes available in software called [MyPaint](http://mypaint.org/about/), basically to allow them to be used directly in GIMP, rather having to install and use MyPaint.

They are totally separate from GIMP's native brushes, and are accessed using the MyPaint brush tool, as opposed to the regular Brush tool used for GIMP's native brushes.  You can use both in any way you want.